# Custom Select with radio buttons as options

Tags: reactjs, forms, select, radio-button, formik

I need to do this in a React component:

[image]

I tried to hide/show a div, but the problem is to set a click listener on the whole page to hide the div, and it seems to be wrong.

I'm also using Formik, but I can't find the way to customize the select Field to have this kind of look.

How is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Try to see how it works in that application that you screenshotted (using browser dev tools) That might give you some ideas about what elements and styles to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `onBlur` event to hide this div, instead of setting an event listener for the whole page.